# javascript must be 4 digist & realtime respone if value is wrong

Tags: javascript, html

Im struggeling with a HTML/Javascript problem.

I need to implemnet an eventhandler with these requirements:

- only digits
- must be 4 digits (min. 4 / max. 4)
- has to be a JavaScript function
- each inputed value hast to be validated realtime and has to be changed if necessary.

```
<td><input type="text" name="plz" value="7777" /> Ort:<input type="text" name="place of residence" value="name of the city" /></td>
```

Comment: *"each inputed value hast to be validated realtime and has to be changed if necessary"* - Please clarify. Also when do you want to make this *validation* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build on this solution

```js
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
const isNumber = /^[0-9]$/i.test(e.key)
const key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
const keyArray = [8, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46] // key codes to allow even when limit reached

if( keyArray.includes(key) ){
return true;
}
else if(!isNumber || this.value.length > 3)
{
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
});
```

```html
<td><input id="input" type="text" name="plz" value="7777" /></td>
```

Comment: yes the requirment says that on each typed digit it has to validate. so if u type a invalid value it has to pop up a warning. 
I like the solution to reset the "input" if entered a 5th digitc. First I thougt about blocking a 5th value. Is there also a solution for it?